# Taking snapshot of a running container via kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to take an image or a snapshot of container running inside pod using `kubectl`?

Via `docker`, it is possible to use the `docker commit` command that creates an image of a container from which we can spawn more containers. I wanted to understand if there was something similar that we could do with `kubectl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, partially because that's not in the kubernetes mental model of anything one would *wish* to do to a cluster, and partially because docker is not the only container runtime kubernetes uses. Every runtime one *could* use underneath kubernetes would need to support that operation, and I doubt they do.

You are welcome to do your own `docker commit` either by getting a shell on the Node, or by running a privileged Pod then connecting to the `docker.sock` via a `volumeMount` and running it that way

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel, I got it. I was able to use node-shell project at  https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-node-shell to get a shell on the node and explore the containers running on the node - your answer makes sense.